# What is the greatest common divisor of $3^{3^{333}}+1$ and $3^{3^{334}}+1$?

Tags: number-theory

What is the greatest common divisor of $3^{3^{333}}+1$ and $3^{3^{334}}+1$ ? Could somebody please help me ?

Comment: Check out the following link to help format your question.

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: what is the greatest common divisor of $n + 1$ and $n^3 + 1$?

Answer (score 2):

Write $T_n=3^{3^n}+1$.  Then
$$\eqalign{T_n^3
  &=(3^{3^n})^3+3(3^{3^n})^2+3(3^{3^n})+1\cr
  &=3^{3^{n+1}}+1+3(3^{3^n})(3^{3^n}+1)\cr
  &=T_{n+1}+3^{3^n+1}T_n\ .\cr}$$
From this you should be able to see an impotant relationship between $T_n$ and $T_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^{3n}+1$ can be factored.